# DRF - Checking for a concrete unique constraint violation when creating and/or validating an object

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a table where composite unique index is set on both DB and Django level. The first question is, how do I catch in DRF that `IntegrityError` has risen exactly because of this given unique constraint violation?

I have come across a code snippet like this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_table'
        unique_together = ('fieldA','fieldB',)

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as err:
            if err.__cause__.pgcode == errorcodes.UNIQUE_VIOLATION:
                # Do something special
```

...but this yields, and besides that, I am feeling like this is not the most appropriate way to achieve the goal. Any ideas?

And the second question is, how do I validate against this same constraint? How should the if-condition look like in the validate method? And should it be done in the validate method or elsewhere?

Comment: If you had set `unique_together` in the model level DRF will take care of it. Why do you want to catch the `IntegrityError` in that place?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776557) on how to use a custom exception handler to convert exceptions into native DRF exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Every type of validation should be done in DRF validation methods i.e. `validate` and `is_valid`. For your case, you should check in your validate method if any object already exists against provided data like this

```
def is_valid(self, raise_exception=True):
    data = self.initial_data
    if TestModel.objects.filter(fieldA=data.get('fieldA'), fieldB=data.get('fieldB').exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Object already exist with {fieldA} and {fieldB}".format(**data)
    return super().is_valid(raise_exception)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you already found the best solution:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            return super().create(validated_data)

        except IntegrityError as error:
            raise ValidationError from error
```

Actually I found an even better solution, using [custom exception handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling). Example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776557/660389).