# Formulate conditional Q on Unique Constraint for exception handling

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, unique-constraint

Django doesn't throw a `ValidationError` because of a missing conditional in `UniqueConstraint`, and I don't know how to formulate a correct one.

---

One of my models contains a unique constraint including a Foreign Key:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    """
    Entry on a List
    """
    name= models.CharField()
    expiration_date = models.DateField()
    list = models.ForeignKey(List,
                             related_name="entries",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['list', 'name'],
                             name='unique_entry')  # Each entry_name may only occur once per list.
        ]
```

When submitting a new Entry which violates this constraint, the database rejects the query and Django throws an unhandled exception `IntegrityError`.

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/) this is intended behaviour:

> Validation of Constraints
>
> In general constraints are **not** checked during **full_clean()**, and do not
> raise **ValidationError**s. Rather you’ll get a database integrity error
> on **save()**. **UniqueConstraints** without a **condition** (i.e. non-partial
> unique constraints) are different in this regard, in that they
> leverage the existing **validate_unique()** logic, and thus enable
> two-stage validation. In addition to **IntegrityError** on **save()**,
> **ValidationError** is also raised during model validation when the
> **UniqueConstraint** is violated.

I would like your help with formulating a conditional, or other suggested solutions to fix this behaviour. The goal is to treat the UniqueConstraint like any other field that won't validate: Django throws a ValidationError which is caught by Django Rest Framework, and ultimately the original request will receive a HTTP 400 Bad Request, instead of 500 Internal Server Error.

Ideally I would like to implement a solution which facilitates throwing a `ValidationError` instead of `IntegrityError` from the model, instead of having to resort to the `Serializer` or `View` (The alternative solution I would like to avoid is querying the database from the `View` to validate the unique constraint.).

An example would be `condition=Q(name=self.name, list=self.list)`.
However, I can't refer to the model instance from within `Meta`:

```
class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['list', 'name'],
                             condition=Q(name=self.name, list=self.list), # this is incorrect
                             name='unique_entry')
        ]
```

Am I trying to do something impossible? Thank you in advance, ideas and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a [DRF custom exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776557/) to automatically convert `IntegrityError`s to DRF `ValidationError`s. This allows all of the validation to be defined once, at the lowest possible point in the application (the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check in the `clean` method of your model. If you then use a `ModelForm`, it will call the `clean()` method, and thus check if the item is valid.

The model thus then looks like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Entry(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
    expiration_date = models.DateField()
    list = models.ForeignKey(
        List,
        related_name='entries',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Entry.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(name=self.name, list_id=self.list_id)
        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError('Can not add an entry with the same name to a list')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['list', 'name'],
                name='unique_entry'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Currently researching whether the DRF `ModelViewset` and `ModelSerializer` call the `clean()` method, because the ValidationError is not thrown. That's a neat solution, I hope I can make it work.

Comment: It seems I should write a validator for the `ModelSerializer`, since its behaviour is different from `ModelForm`:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework

Thanks Willem!